# How to open app specific activity using android app link or deep link? Also how to generate & code for multiple dynamic links for single app?

Tags: android

> I am trying to generate dynamic link to open specific activity from
>   app link. I am succedded to open single activity from firebase dynamic
>   link but unable to code and understand to do same for multiple link in
>   my app.
>
> I created firebase project and connected my app with it. Then compiled
>   firebase below invites library:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
```

> Then entered below intent filter in a manifest activity tag:

```
<activity android:name=".HandleAppLinkActivity">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <data android:host="example.com"
             android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> Then handled dynamic link intent using getDynamicsLink in my activity:

```
private void handleDynamicLinks() {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())
       .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
            // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
            Uri deepLink = null;
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
            }
            }
       }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                 Log.w("TAG", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
            }
        });
}
```

> I want to handle multiple activities at one place only. Dynamic host
>   link will be same for all link with different postfix. So that in
>   getDynamicLink if I check using last substring if Suppose I want to
>   open VendorActivity then base_host_url/vendor then it will redirect
>   accordingly.

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdi found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.4) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.5.0)
```

> Also if I am integrating all these getting above error

Comment: Please note that Firebase Invites has been deprecated in favour of Firebase Dynamic Links and will be discontinued on 24 January 2020: https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation

Comment: Okay....thanks for the information Edric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Integrate dynamic links by using 3 simple steps:
>
> **1) Configuration on both firebase console and to your project**
>
> Firebase dynamic links are hosted on the customisable subdomain look
>   something like https://abcde.page.link where .page.link is subdomain.
>   Firebase creates a mini website at this subdomain to host the links.
>   Also on that mini website it automatically generates assetlinks.json
>   to map dynamic links to your app.
>
> a) Add your project to firebase
>
> b) For dynamic links add both SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprint
>
> c) Add dynamic links dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:17.0.0'
```

> d)Go to firebase console -> select project -> select dynamic link menu
>   -> Get started: Add the subdomain you want to use for eg: https://abcde.page.link. If you dont want to use page.link subdomain
>   you can also use your own. Enter domain www.myapp.page.link and your
>   subdomain is ready to go

e) Make sure your app is properly configured.

> To check use: the_name_you_chose.page.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json
>   provides configuration details of your project.
>
> **2) Create a firebase dynamic link**
>
> a)Create new dynamic link will getting prepopulated short
>   link/path(customizable)
>
> b)Set up dynamic link same as short url.
>
> c)Add app behaviour setting. Next d) Finally create
>
> **3) Finally receive a dynamic link**

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
           android:host="myapp.page.link"
           android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

> Add this intent-filter to launcher in manifest. And handle dynamic
>   link in your splash using below code:

```
public void handleDeepLink(){
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        Uri data = intent.getData();

                        if (data.toString().toLowerCase().contains("catoffers")){
                            if (data.getQueryParameter("catoffers") != null){
                                          //TO DO                 
                            }
                        }else if (data.toString().toLowerCase().contains("offer")){
                            if (data.getQueryParameter("offer") != null){
                               //TO DO                                     
                            }
                        }else {
                              //TO DO         
                             finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w("TAG", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
}
```

> 4) Check your link:

```
https://myapp.page.link/custom/?title=hadle
```